# When I use the Wacom Tablet Configuration in Ubuntu's settings to calibrate my tablet, where are the settings saved?

Tags: multiple-monitors, xfce, tablet, wacom

Ubuntu's Wacom tablet calibration works great, but other desktops (xfce for example) do not work nearly as well when using 2 monitors. I've been searching around for a solution, but it occurred to me that if I could locate the saved calibration settings from when I ran Ubuntu's calibration app, I might be able to use them to manually calibrate my tablet in xfce. Does anyone know where the settings are saved?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the actual answer to your question (where the calibration values are stored) but let me give you some pointers on how to obtain these values:

By using the `xinput` command-line tool you can query all properties of you tablet.

```
$ xinput

⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Optical USB Mouse                id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell Dell USB Keyboard Hub                id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell Dell USB Keyboard Hub                id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

This will give you the list of devices. Look for your Wacom device (not present in my example), and remember its `id` value. The IDs may change upon reboot, btw.

Then query the device properties by issuing

```
$ xinput --list-props <id>
```

where `<id>` is the ID number of your device. It will now show a list of all the properties that are set for your Wacom tablet.

Now run a calibration in Ubuntu and purposely really screw it up by clicking in wrong places. Then store the properties in a file:

```
$ xinput --list-props <id>  >xinput-cal-wrong.txt
```

Then run a calibration in Ubuntu and do it correctly. Again, store the values in a file:

```
$ xinput --list-props <id>  >xinput-cal-correct.txt
```

Now compare the text files, and watch the differences. These are obviously the properties that the calibration tool changes, and you can record these values. You can apply them in XFCE on the command-line by setting the properties, for example for the `Area` properties:

```
$ xinput --set-prop <id> 'Area' -20 12 87064 65691
```

You can put the necessary commands in your `~/.xinitrc` file, which is called when your window system starts. I also recommend to look at the `xsetwacom` command-line tool, which has similar syntax and can also be used to get and set properties.